# Vaadin 7 Refresher addon doesn't work

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm migrating from Vaadin 6 to Vaadin 7. 
After changing Refresher for Vaadin 6 to Refresher for Vaadin 7, It seems that I should just change addComponent(refresher) to addExtension(refresher). But unfortunatelly when I did it I recieved an empty page instead of my component. Can anybody help? I don't fully understand what I should do..

Comment: just to check, have you also updated refresher addon to new version, i.e. 1.2.1.7?

Comment: of course I updated it

Comment: does it also throw an exception on the server logs? usually blank page should mean something go wrong with an error.

Comment: no, it doesn't throw an exception, and without refresher it works fine, but of course without refreshes. Empty page appears after addition of addExtension(refresher) on my component

Comment: It works for me. Have you compiler a new widget set? Check the output in the browser debug console. Also, try adding it to a different component, for example a layout.

Comment: what type of layout is containing the refresher?

Comment: @Ingo Kegel Of course I compiled widgetsets. Browser debug shows that there is nothing in my component. In different componrnts it doesn't work too

Comment: @Anatoly, did you find the solution? I have the same exact problem

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example code of I used:

```
public class RefresherDemo extends UI  {
    Refresher refresher;
    Label timeLabel;    

    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        timeLabel = new Label(getTime());

        refresher = new Refresher();
        refresher.setRefreshInterval(500);
        refresher.addListener(new RefreshListener(){
            @Override
            public void refresh(Refresher source) {
                timeLabel.setValue(getTime());
            }
        });
        addExtension(refresher);        

        layout.addComponent(timeLabel);

    }

    public String getTime(){
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String d = dateFormat.format(date);
        return d;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I,m trying to add refresher not in UI, but in my custom component which lies in application UI

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same exact problem and I found out how to solve it. I didn't know about the custom widgetset. It's necessary to add a reference to web.xml like this:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mypackage.AppWidgetSet</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Hope helps somebody